# Power Loss in lower gears

Tags: power, gears, mondeo

I have a 2004 Ford Mondeo 2.0 TDCI. I have heard about something called the EGR (Exhaust-Gas Recirculation) that can get clogged up and need cleaning. Is this right? Also, where would I find this on the engine?

Comment: EGR can build up deposits coming from exhaust gas in your intake duct, which in turn can cause a restriction in airflow. I don't see the relation between that and powerloss specifically in lower gears though. The overall  performance of the engine would be less, i would think.